# what is the Tensorflow batch size when you use high-level API tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
def binaryClassify_DNN(units,steps,trainingFilePath,testingFilePath,modelPath):

    # Data sets

    # Load datasets.
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=trainingFilePath,target_dtype=np.float)
    test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=testingFilePath,target_dtype=np.float)

    # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=units,n_classes=2,model_dir=modelPath,optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1))

    # Fit model.
    classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
                   y=training_set.target,
                   steps=steps)

    # Evaluate accuracy.
    accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,
                                         y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]
    print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))
```

I've coded above source little changed from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/tflearn/index.html#tf-contrib-learn-quickstart

As you can see, I didn't add parameter for `batch_size` which I can add to `classifier.fi()`

I tried executing this code and it seemed that it was looping without batch size.
I mean that it looks like training with the full size of data instead of mini batch.

Is it true?

I'd like to know what is the default setting for batch size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry i should have looked into source code before posting

```
def fit(self, x=None, y=None, input_fn=None, steps=None, batch_size=None,
      monitors=None, max_steps=None):
"""Trains a model given training data `x` predictions and `y` targets.

Args:
  x: Matrix of shape [n_samples, n_features...]. Can be iterator that
     returns arrays of features. The training input samples for fitting the
     model. If set, `input_fn` must be `None`.
  y: Vector or matrix [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]. Can be
     iterator that returns array of targets. The training target values
     (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression). If set,
     `input_fn` must be `None`.
  input_fn: Input function. If set, `x`, `y`, and `batch_size` must be
    `None`.
  steps: Number of steps for which to train model. If `None`, train forever.
    If set, `max_steps` must be `None`.
  batch_size: minibatch size to use on the input, defaults to first
    dimension of `x`. Must be `None` if `input_fn` is provided.
  monitors: List of `BaseMonitor` subclass instances. Used for callbacks
    inside the training loop.
  max_steps: Number of total steps for which to train model. If `None`,
    train forever. If set, `steps` must be `None`.

    Two calls to `fit(steps=100)` means 200 training
    iterations. On the other hand, two calls to `fit(max_steps=100)` means
    that the second call will not do any iteration since first call did
    all 100 steps.

Returns:
  `self`, for chaining.

Raises:
  ValueError: If `x` or `y` are not `None` while `input_fn` is not `None`.
  ValueError: If both `steps` and `max_steps` are not `None`.
"""
```

As you can see, the default batch_size is the first dimension of 'x'

Comment: If you don't set it, then it is the first dimension of x, but you can set it with the parameter and use it